# For loop to create headers based on column names in csv python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, header

I am trying to do a for loop to append my headers of an excel to separate variables as header1, 2, 3 and so on. For example, In the attached image my excel has 5 columns and I need my results to be as below, could someone please help, Thanks in advance

```
header1 = 'Statistics'
header2 = 'Machine Learning'
header3 = 'R Language'
header4 = 'NLP'
header5 = 'Data Engineering'
```

Attached is the image of my excel header

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for.

But to me it sounds like you want to retrieve the column labels of a pandas dataframe.
You can do so like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/your/file/excel.csv", skiprows = 1)
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5 = df.columns.values
```

We skip the first row because, If I remember correctly, when reading `.csv` files the first row is a default csv thing.

Comment: Hi VBence, Thanks for your answer, the header count is not static and I want the header names to be dynamically created, Thanks again

Comment: Dynamically created?

Comment: Hi VBence, For example, the length of headers is not static and it can 5 or 6 or even more than that, so based on the length of the column header1, 2, 3 ...has to be created.

Comment: If it is dynamic, than you can just use a list to store them no?
´headers = df.columns.values´